# Why address posted with place API is not getting set?

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api

I'm adding my interested **Place** to Google Place with my APP. Place is getting added successfully, but the address field is empty.

Here is Code:

```
{
    GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey(googlePlaceAPIKEY)

    let placesClient = GMSPlacesClient.shared()

    let userAddedPlace = GMSUserAddedPlace()
    userAddedPlace.name = "NightClub & Bar"
    userAddedPlace.address = "48 Gandhi Road, Bandra, Mumbai, Maharastra"
    userAddedPlace.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(19.017615 , 72.856164)
    userAddedPlace.phoneNumber = "9999999999"
    userAddedPlace.website = "http://www.google.com/"
    userAddedPlace.types = ["bar"]

    placesClient.add(userAddedPlace, callback: { (place, error) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            print("Add Place error: \(error)")
            return
        }

        if let place = place {
            print("Added place with placeID \(place.placeID)")
        }
    })
}
```

I can see "NightClub & Bar" in my place list but the address *"48 Gandhi Road, Bandra, Mumbai, Maharastra"* is not there.

Can anyone tell me what mistake I made?

Comment: you said that this line         userAddedPlace.address = "48 Gandhi Road, Bandra, Mumbai, Maharastra"
 is empty

Comment: Yes, its nil in vicinity, for the response of places

Comment: add this `print("Added Place name \(place.name)")
    print("Added Place address \(place.formattedAddress)")` and try

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, Issue is due to I'm using web-api to fetch addresses. If i go with IOS-API then its working fine.

Comment: can you show that code, check once the special char added or not

Comment: which code? code for fetch places?

Comment: show relevant code for this Issue is due to I'm using web-api to fetch addresses

Comment: if self.pageToken.characters.count > 0 {
            stringURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=\(currentLocation!.latitude),\(currentLocation!.longitude)&rankby=distance&sensor=false&type=restaurant%7Ccafe%7Cbar&key=\(googlePlaceAPIKEY)&pagetoken=\(self.pageToken)"
        }
        else{
            stringURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=\(currentLocation!.latitude),\(currentLocation!.longitude)&rankby=distance&sensor=false&type=restaurant%7Ccafe%7Cbar&key=\(googlePlaceAPIKEY)"
        }

Comment: googlePlaceAPIKEY is ios key or web key

Comment: This will work of for as i did not set secure for any of api